# Mysterious KDE hang and/or restart

Tags: kubuntu, kde, crash, syslog

I use Kubuntu and it's been working fine for years, but in the past few months I either have regular (every few days) screen hangs where nothing responds for a few seconds to tens of seconds, or I get kicked back to the login prompt losing all my running programs (hardly better than a full reboot). I believe this is info related to those crashes (from syslog):

```
INFO: task jbd2/dm-1-8:426 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
    Tainted: P           OE     4.18.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
jbd2/dm-1-8     D    0   426      2 0x80000000
Call Trace:
__schedule+0x29e/0x840
? bit_wait_timeout+0xa0/0xa0
schedule+0x2c/0x80
io_schedule+0x16/0x40
bit_wait_io+0x11/0x50
__wait_on_bit+0x74/0x90
out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x90/0xb0
? init_wait_var_entry+0x50/0x50
__wait_on_buffer+0x32/0x40
jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x1313/0x16c2
? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x53/0x80
kjournald2+0xc8/0x270
? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
kthread+0x120/0x140
? commit_timeout+0x20/0x20
? kthread_bind+0x40/0x40
ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
INFO: task plasmashell:5213 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
    Tainted: P           OE     4.18.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
plasmashell     D    0  5213      1 0x00000000
Call Trace:
__schedule+0x29e/0x840
? bit_wait_timeout+0xa0/0xa0
schedule+0x2c/0x80
io_schedule+0x16/0x40
bit_wait_io+0x11/0x50
__wait_on_bit+0x74/0x90
? guard_bio_eod+0x32/0x100
out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x90/0xb0
? init_wait_var_entry+0x50/0x50
__wait_on_buffer+0x32/0x40
ext4_bread+0x97/0xa0
__ext4_read_dirblock+0x34/0x2c0
ext4_dx_find_entry+0x113/0x190
ext4_find_entry+0x431/0x540
? __d_alloc+0x29/0x250
? d_alloc_parallel+0x9d/0x490
ext4_lookup+0x78/0x210
__lookup_slow+0x9b/0x150
lookup_slow+0x3a/0x60
walk_component+0x1bf/0x4b0
? link_path_walk+0x29e/0x540
path_lookupat.isra.45+0x75/0x200
? kmem_cache_free+0x1b3/0x1e0
filename_lookup.part.59+0xa0/0x170
? __check_object_size+0xa1/0x178
? strncpy_from_user+0x4f/0x180
user_path_at_empty+0x3e/0x50
do_faccessat+0xa7/0x240
? ksys_read+0xa4/0xc0
__x64_sys_access+0x1b/0x20
do_syscall_64+0x5a/0x110
entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
RIP: 0033:0x7f800d6bd097
Code: Bad RIP value.
RSP: 002b:00007ffe5e623c78 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000015
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffe5e623e20 RCX: 00007f800d6bd097
RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000558ea6b774d8
RBP: 0000000000400000 R08: 00007f800d797c40 R09: 0000000000000001
R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007ffe5e623e00
R13: 00007ffe5e623c90 R14: 0000000000400000 R15: 00007ffe5e623e00
```

Can anybody enlighten me on what may be the cause or where else to look ?